# Полнотекстовый поиск в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаемся реализовать полнотекстовый поиск в Oracle, но никак не пойму, как правильно составить запрос для поиска:
Задача состоит в следующем:

1. При написании слова должны быть отображены все вхождения и
   отсортированы по релевантности. При этом при запросе "рок" в
   результае поиска должны отобразится "сырок", "рок" и
   "прокрастинация" отсортированые по релевантности.
2. При написании нескольких слов в поисковом запросе должны выводится ячейки содержащие как все слова, так и некоторые из
   запроса. Так же отсортированые по релевантности.
3. Должна быть возможность объеденять слова в группы. Т.е. , например при выделении слова в кавычки должно искаться строго такое
   вхождение, без раздельного поиска по словам.

Пока получилось реализовать только часть из этого, используя оператор ABOUT ([ссылка на документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#CCREF9901)), он идеально подходит под второй пункт задачи. Т.е. если я пишу запрос вида:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), name from table WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'ABOUT('some text')', 1) > 0 ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC;
```

То я получу следующие результаты:

```
some text
some
text
```

Вопрос как объеденить это с поиском по фразе, и с поиском частичных вхождений?